# Cannot simulate authentication in Symfony functional test

Tags: authentication, testing, symfony, functional-testing

I followed the [instructions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/http_authentication.html) in the cookbook to simulate HTTP authentication inside my functional tests.

I added the following to my **config_test.yml**:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured Demo Area"
```

And this is how my test looks like:

```
class CourseControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->loadFixtures(array(
            'Herudio\Bundle\UserBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadUserData',
            'Herudio\Bundle\CourseBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadCategoryData',
            'Herudio\Bundle\CourseBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadCourseData',
        ));
    }

    public function testListDisplaysAllEntities()
    {
        $client = static::createClient(array(), array(
            'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'admin',
            'PHP_AUTH_PW'   => 'admin',
        ));

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/courses');

        $this->assertCount(1, $crawler->filter('tbody tr'), 'Unexpected entity count for GET /courses/');
    }
}
```

However, when I run the test, I get redirected to **/login**.

I already ensured that the User entity is created correctly.

Note: I'm using FOSUserBundle for authentication.

Comment: I have written functional tests for my Symfony app that's also using the FOSUserBundle. I had to simulate the browser filling in the login form, clicking submit and signing in, then asserting the expected content after login. Have you considered doing that instead?

Comment: That said, what you're doing is probably recommended more.

Comment: @alessandro1997 I think you should add an in memory user provider section as well. E.g. like this https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/config/security.yml#L13-18

Comment: ...and add `provider: in_memory` to the `http_basic` section

Comment: @1ed: why should I add an in_memory provider when I can use FOSUserBundle? I just don't understand while the login data isn't recognized correctly.

Comment: @alessandro1997 http basic doesn't use cookies but form login does... maybe I'm wrong, but I think you have to create the session and store it in a cookie by hand like [here](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle/blob/master/Test/WebTestCase.php#L342-385) if you want to use FOSUser... or you should use [LiipFunctionalTestBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle)

Comment: Solved, I just forgot to enable my user when creating it. :)

Comment: @AlessandroDesantis: you can answer to this question and accept the answer, this question seems to be "open" at this moment.